# How to set a font for a text in Css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to set font's like "**Intro Black Regular**" for text's in css?!
The IDE detects '**Black**' as a color, not a part of font's name.

Comment: 1) Declare the `@font-face` in CSS or if it's a web font, include / import the relevant stylesheet. 2) Set `font-family: 'Intro Black Regular';` in CSS

Comment: Looks like some of the answers given might answer your question, but for future reference, more information and code are important to getting accurate help.

Answer (score 3):

You need follow 3 steps to use font for text

1. Setup `@font-face`
2. Set `font-family` name
3. Use `font-family` in css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}

div {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The @font-face Rule</h1>

<div>With CSS, websites can finally use fonts other than the pre selected "web-safe" fonts.</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier, do not support the WOFF format (only supports EOT format).</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if that font family is not available in your local or server, you have to install that, https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Fonts-on-Your-PC

after that you can use it as - example

```
font-family: "IntroW01-Black";
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try font-family?

```
font-family: 'YOUR-FONT-NAME';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
// This stylesheet help to use google font stylesheet
<h1 style="font-family:'Tangerine', serif">Font Family</h1>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation. In this case what were you trying to show?